# JavaScript id= to name= in a form

Tags: html, forms, geolocation

A have a JavaScript that handles localisation.
That gives me a

```
Position: <input type="text" id="Position1" name="Position1" value="">
```

This works, and i get the current position on the webpage.

Now, I want to have that position in a form and give it to my SQL by a php script. The php works.

I hva tried:

```
<input type="hidden" name="poss" id="Position1">
```

and I know this does not work.
But how do I do it? How do I convert from id= to name= ??

Script:

```
        <script>
    window.onload = function(){
     var x = document.getElementById('Position1');
      function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            } else {
                x.value = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
            }
         }

         function showPosition(position) {
           x.value = "" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;
              }
    getLocation();
    };

    </script>

Position: <input type="text" id="Position1" name="Position1" value="">

<input type="hidden" name="poss" id="Position1">

<input type="submit"  style="height:40px;width:350px" />
</form>
```

Comment: You cannot have duplicate IDs. Also, I'm still unsure exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: What do you mean by "convert from id= to name="?  What specifically are you trying to do and what specifically isn't working?

Comment: Thank you all. I was, as you say, trying to convert. But, i was looking at the solution from the wrong angle. Pivote gave me the direction and the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with `document.getElementsByName('poss')[0].value = "" + position.coords.latitude + "," + position.coords.longitude;` it should work